# How to be more lazy with Perl? and other assorted questions about programming habits

Tags: perl, lazy-evaluation

Last night, I wrote roughly 200 lines of crappy perl code, complete with spaghetti code, undefined variables that I couldn't debug, and much, much more. Ultimately, I put it up on PerlMonks and waited. I got this as the most helpful response:

> Over 200 lines of spaghetti code with input parsing stirred in amongst everything else in one sub. No wonder you are having trouble debugging this puppy! Some hints that may help clean things up:
>
> > - Refactor your code to move all the input parsing out of the LHCC sub then pass the parsed data into the sub. That lets you write and debug the sub without having to get the input data parsing right to start with.
> > - Don't use goto
> > - Don't use empty {} in if/elsif/else statements - they obscure the fail conditions
> > - Don't repeat blocks of code - use a sub. That includes the large number of places where your code dies with a long and meaningless error message. Use a sub and pass a context to be included in the message. That will both clean up the code and help with debugging logic errors.
> > - Don't code for stuff that can't happen (n % 2 can only be 0 or 1) to avoid cluttering the code and obscuring the logic
> > - Use next to "early exit" loops. That avoids nesting code and makes it easier to understand.
> > - Check $key (and die) before using it.
> > - Why my @StatementsKeys = keys %Statements; when @StatementsKeys is not used anywhere?
>
> I'll follow up with a somewhat tided version of your code in due course, but there are a lot of lines to delete and it's taking a while! ;).

That's all very good advice for Perl code. But I have problems with implementing his advice and truly being a lazy coder. For some strange reason, I can't implement what he's saying into everything I program, which I'm pretty sure is how you learn true good programming. I have 2 queries:

First, how would you make this quick script optimized and better, codewise? I think after I see this optimized, I will be able to start going in a better direction with my code. BTW, this is not the code referred to in the above message.

```
ORIGINAL:

print "
Welcome to the Casio-Maxim Quadrilateral Identification\n
Algorithm. In order to identify said quadrilateral,\n
you must have the coordinates of all 4 vertices.\n
When you are ready to input your coordines, type\n
'ready.' Type 'quit' to exit the CMQIA.\n\n";

my $choice = <STDIN>;
if ($choice =~ /quit/i) {
  if (!&Unit6()) {
    return 0;
  }
}
elsif ($choice =~ /ready/i) {

}
else {
  print "\nCould not interpret, try again\n";
  goto ORIGINAL;
}

print
"\nFor shape ABCD, in which point A has coordinates (X1, Y1), B has coordinates\n\n(X2, Y2), C has coordinates (X3, Y3), and D has coordinates (X4, Y4),\n\nX1 = ";

my $AX = <STDIN>;
chomp $AX;
if ($AX !~ /^-?\d+\.?\d*$/) {
  print "\nMust be numeric value.\n";
  goto ORIGINAL;
}
print "\nY1 = ";

my $AY = <STDIN>;
chomp $AY;
if ($AY !~ /^-?\d+\.?\d*$/) {
  print "\nMust be numeric value.\n";
  goto ORIGINAL;
}
print "\nX2 = ";

my $BX = <STDIN>;
chomp $BX;
if ($BX !~ /^-?\d+\.?\d*$/) {
  print "\nMust be numeric value.\n";
  goto ORIGINAL;
}
print "\nY2 = ";

my $BY = <STDIN>;
chomp $BY;
if ($BY !~ /^-?\d+\.?\d*$/) {
  print "\nMust be numeric value.\n";
  goto ORIGINAL;
}
print "\nX3 = ";

my $CX = <STDIN>;
chomp $CX;
if ($CX !~ /^-?\d+\.?\d*$/) {
  print "\nMust be numeric value.\n";
  goto ORIGINAL;
}
print "\nY3 = ";

my $CY = <STDIN>;
chomp $CY;
if ($CY !~ /^-?\d+\.?\d*$/) {
  print "\nMust be numeric value.\n";
  goto ORIGINAL;
}
print "\nX4 = ";

my $DX = <STDIN>;
chomp $DX;
if ($DX !~ /^-?\d+\.?\d*$/) {
  print "\nMust be numeric value.\n";
  goto ORIGINAL;
}
print "\nY4 = ";

my $DY = <STDIN>;
chomp $DY;
if ($DY !~ /^-?\d+\.?\d*$/) {
  print "\nMust be numeric value.\n";
  goto ORIGINAL;
}

my $SAB = ($BX - $AX)**2 + ($BY - $AY)**2;
my $AB  = sqrt($SAB);
my $SBC = ($CX - $BX)**2 + ($CY - $BY)**2;
my $BC  = sqrt($SBC);
my $SCD = ($DX - $CX)**2 + ($DY - $CY)**2;
my $CD  = sqrt($SCD);
my $SDA = ($AX - $DX)**2 + ($AY - $DY)**2;
my $DA  = sqrt($SDA);
my $SAC = ($CX - $AX)**2 + ($CY - $AY)**2;
my $AC  = sqrt($SAC);
my $SBD = ($DX - $BX)**2 + ($DY - $BY)**2;
my $BD  = sqrt($SBD);

my $MAB = eval { ($BY - $AY) / { $BX - $AX } };
if ($@) {
  print "\nUndefined or No Slope. Sorry, cannot compute.\n";
  goto ORIGINAL;
}

my $MBC = eval { ($CY - $BY) / { $CX - $BX } };
if ($@) {
  print "\nUndefined or No Slope. Sorry, cannot compute.\n";
  goto ORIGINAL;
}

my $MCD = eval { ($DY - $CY) / { $DX - $CX } };
if ($@) {
  print "\nUndefined or No Slope. Sorry, cannot compute.\n";
  goto ORIGINAL;
}

my $MDA = eval { ($AY - $DY) / { $AX - $DX } };
if ($@) {
  print "\nUndefined or No Slope. Sorry, cannot compute.\n";
  goto ORIGINAL;
}

my $MAC = eval { ($CY - $AY) / { $CX - $AX } };
if ($@) {
  print "\nUndefined or No Slope. Sorry, cannot compute.\n";
  goto ORIGINAL;
}

my $MBD = eval { ($DY - $BY) / { $DX - $BX } };
if ($@) {
  print "\nUndefined or No Slope. Sorry, cannot compute.\n";
  goto ORIGINAL;
}

my $ShapeName;
if ($MAB == $MCD) {
  if ($MBC == $MDA) {
    if ((-1 / $MAB) == $MDA && (-1 / $MBC) == $MCD) {
      if ($AB == $BC) {
        $ShapeName = "square";
      }
      else {
        $ShapeName = "rectangle";
      }
    }
    else {
      if ($AB == $BC) {
        $ShapeName = "rhombus";
      }
      else {
        $ShapeName = "parallelogram";
      }
    }
  }
  else {
    if ($BC == $DA) {
      $ShapeName = "isosceles trapezoid";
    }
    else {
      $ShapeName = "trapezoid";
    }
  }
}
else {
  if ($MBC == $MDA) {
    if ($AB == $CD) {
      $ShapeName = "isosceles trapezoid";
    }
    else {
      $ShapeName = "trapezoid";
    }
  }
  else {
    if ((-1 / $MAC) == $MBD) {
      $ShapeName = "kite";
    }
    else {
      $ShapeName = "quadrilateral";
    }
  }
}

print "
Shape ABCD is a $ShapeName.\n
AB = $AB or the square root of ($SAB)\n
BC = $BC or the square root of ($SBC)\n
CD = $CD or the square root of ($SCD)\n
DA = $DA or the square root of ($SDA)\n
AC = $AC or the square root of ($SAC)\n
BD = $BD or the square root of ($SBD)\n
Slope of AB = $MAB\n
Slope of BC = $MBC\n
Slope of CD = $MCD\n
Slope of DA = $MDA\n
Slope of AC = $MAC\n
Slope of BD = $MBD\n";

goto ORIGINAL;
```

Second, it would be a lot easier if I had a mentor to help me with coding so that I don't have to just keep posting on PerlMonks and Stack Overflow, but I could just go ask my mentor. Unfortunately, I have since lost contact with the best coder I ever met who always helped me out with my code, and there's nobody at my school that I know who's really good at Perl and Python-esque languages. Any advice for finding my code mentor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, you're using a label and gotos to simulate normal program flow control statements.

There are very, very few cases where a `goto` statement is appropriate in any language.  And backwards jumping Perl is especially bad.  In this case, you could have simply used:

```
while (1) {
  ...
  } else {
    print "\nCould not interpret, try again\n";
    continue;
  }
  ...
}
```

Let the language work with you.

Next, I like that you're declaring your variables, are you also ensuring that you `use strict;` at the top of your file so that declaring your variables is useful?

Next, this part of the code is repeated quite a bit with only minor changes:

```
my $AX = <STDIN>;
chomp $AX;
if ($AX !~ /^-?\d+\.?\d*$/) {
  print "\nMust be numeric value.\n"; goto ORIGINAL;
}
```

You can take this and make it a sub like so:

```
sub parse_input {
  my $coord = shift(_@);
  chomp $coord;
  if ($coord !~ /^-?\d+\.?\d*$/) {
    print "\nMust be numeric value.\n";
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

And then call it like so:

```
my $AX = <STDIN>;
continue unless (parse_input($AX));

my $AY = <STDIN>;
continue unless (parse_input($AY));

my $BX = <STDIN>;
continue unless (parse_input($BX));

my $BY = <STDIN>;
continue unless (parse_input($BY));

my $CX = <STDIN>;
continue unless (parse_input($CX));

my $CY = <STDIN>;
continue unless (parse_input($CY));

my $DX = <STDIN>;
continue unless (parse_input($DX));

my $DY = <STDIN>;
continue unless (parse_input($DY));
```

Next, you have lots of repeated code that looks like this:

```
my $SAB = ($BX-$AX)**2 + ($BY-$AY)**2;
my $AB = sqrt($SAB);
```

Sub it out and make the language work for you.  It's also super hard to figure out typos from that, it's dense and difficult to read.

```
sub pyth {
  my ($AX, $AY, $BX, $BY) = @_;
  return sqrt(($BX-$AX)**2 + ($BY-$AY)**2);
}
```

And call it:

```
my $AB = pyth($AX, $AY, $BX, $BY);
my $BC = pyth($BX, $BY, $CX, $CY);
```

etc.

Next, your slope finding functions employs an eval trick to capture divide by zero.  However, we can just directly check for that.  It's much clearer.

```
my $MAB = eval{($BY-$AY)/{$BX-$AX}}; if ($@) {print "\nUndefined or No Slope. Sorry, cannot compute.\n"; goto ORIGINAL;}
```

Becomes:

```
if ($BX-$AX == 0) {
  print "\nUndefined or No Slope. Sorry, cannot compute.\n";
  continue;
}

my $MAB = ($BY-$AY)/($BX-$AX);
```

And of course, because this is a part of the code that you repeat a bunch, you should put it in a sub.

A good rule of thumb is, if you have to write code twice, it can probably stay, if you have it repeated 3 or more times, or it's long, you ought to put it in a function.

Next, you will want to handle those cases where the slope is undefined, because those are still valid shapes.

Finally, put in some comments, especially in the shape identification code, the precedence isn't immediately apparent, so you'll want to explain the logic in plain english first.

Comment: Thank you very much sir, you did exactly what I needed. I think I get the hang of things now.

Comment: The last part with the comments is probably the most important part, especially when you're just starting out.  Depending on the complexity of the problem I have been known to write comments that look like this: http://pastebin.com/5SwDymQP  And this is a good thing.  Remember that the purpose of a programming language is to help you understand what you're telling the computer to do.  If you're trying to be too clever or terse, then you're only hurting yourself. :)

Comment: Your use of `&sub()` to call subroutines is *bad advice* and should be ignored. As is your preference for `if !...` in place of `unless`.

Comment: The majority of this post is the opposite of received wisdom. In particular, *"The last part with the comments"* is probably the *most misleading*. In general a program should describe what it is doing without the help of comments. It is extremely rare that a program in *any* language cannot be better written without the use of comments. If you have written a statement that you think needs a comment then you should reexamine your code.

Comment: "In general a program should describe what it is doing without the help of comments." I agree.  And in general most programs do.  But in the case of this program, determining what kind of quadrilateral 4 sets of points are isn't immediately obvious to the most casual observer, and some comments can help, not just with the rereading, but also with getting the writing straight and bug free as well.  It's like rubber ducky debugging, but you keep a record of it around.

Comment: I also updated the code to reflect best practices.  I was unaware that calling a sub with `&` was depreciated, can you let me know why?